# Why android ndk function AAsetManager_open error, when the path is like this

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
string relativePath = "scripts/test.pb"; // this is ok
string relativePath = "./scripts/test.pb"; // this can not open the file"
AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(FileUtilsAndroid::assetmanager,
                           relativePath.c_str(),
                           AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
```

When i use this function to open android apk file, the "relativePath" contains "." can not work. i can not understand why? and i can not see the source code of "AAssetManager_open", so just need help.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code for [AAssetManager_open](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/28a5f8f4fc47e9623327caa5a4a642f8c17569b1/native/android/asset_manager.cpp#L87) , you will see that it calls [AssetManager::open](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/androidfw/AssetManager.cpp#L474) , which does this:

```
String8 assetName(kAssetsRoot);
assetName.appendPath(fileName);
```

where [kAssetsRoot](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/androidfw/AssetManager.cpp#L73) is a static const char* defined to hold the value "assets"

If you use "./scripts/test.pb" as the filename this will yield "assets/./scripts/test.pb" (which is a valid unix pathname, i.e. you can add as many "./" or "/" and it should still be a valid path), but inside [AssetManager::openNonAssetInPathLocked](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/androidfw/AssetManager.cpp#L810) it appends "assets/./scripts/test.pb" to ap.path which maybe causes problems further down the callstack i.e. in [Asset::createFromFile](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/androidfw/Asset.cpp#L121) which calls [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [_FileAsset::openChunk](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/androidfw/Asset.cpp#L373) on the given filepath.

Comment: thanks, when i look the source code, i find the "open" function is not to open file on disk, just to search file in a file set. so it can not find the asset in the set.

Comment: Which open function? You can certainly open files on disk with AAssetManager_open and read their contents using AAssetManager_read. See https://gist.github.com/DrSkyLizard/bb6eac53d22cd75aed34